# Как изменить installargs для уже устанвленного пакета chocolatey?

Tags: chocolatey

Например, я установил Opera командой:

```
choco install opera
```

теперь chocolatey корректно обновляет оперу. Но опера, сволочь такая, постоянно добавляет иконки в таксбар и на рабочий стол.

я хочу, чтобы обновления выполнялись с аргументом `--installargs` (не путать с `--params`), как будто установка была выполнена командой:

```
choco install opera --installargs "-desktopshortcut 0 -pintotaskbar 0"
```

где хранятся эти `--installargs`?